# how to get around could not convert string to float error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I guess this must be a super basic question, but recently I've been using a database and I'm trying to preprocess some data. Unfortunately I can't create a price change column as I can't convert a string to a float.

```
Example_Helper = DB_tool() 
df = Example_Helper.Get_Factor(name_in = ['Euro Stoxx 50 Pr'])
df.sort_values(by=['TICKER','Date'], inplace=True)
df['change_in_price'] = df[float('close')].diff()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'close'
```

I've print the data so I was able to check that the column headers are not part of the data frame, yet when I go to use the float function it returns the error. I've added a picture of the first few rows of the data. Any help would be much appreciated.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOgxS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
df['change_in_price'] = df[float('close')].diff()
```

to this:

```
df['change_in_price'] = df['close'].astype(float).diff()
```

or:

```
df['change_in_price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['close']).diff()
```

Comment: Life saver! :) If you don't mind, could you quickly explain why what I did messed it up?

Comment: You were trying to convert the string 'close' to float, not the column 'close'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.to_numeric()` -- the `errors='coerce'` will convert to a numeric value, or give NaN.  You can then find which values failed to convert by using `.isna()` in a boolean mask:

```
x = pd.to_numeric(df['mark'], errors='coerce')
x[ x.isna() ]
```